# Facebook Graph Api: Get Pages I am Admin Of

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have searched about this topic a lot, but I did'nt got any solution that suits my needs.

What I want is, when I call `me/accounts` , it gives me all the pages and apps I am associated with. But the thing is, I want to get only those pages of which I am an `Admin` not those in which I am linked as a Developer or a QA. I got a workaround to use `isAdmin` method once i get the page ids, but that takes a lot much time to check for each page.

Can I get something that can help me to get all pages I am admin of in one call. Its really critical.

Thanks for your help in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with FQL.

```
SELECT page_id, role, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid=me() and type != 'APPLICATION'
```